Google sheets cells jumped all over the place
I am currently having a project that I can measure force from a punch and then send that data to google sheets from an ESP32, but there was a twist, the cell jumped all over the place and I couldn't figure this out. Here's a code in the App Script:
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var result = 'Ok';
  if (e.parameter == 'undefined') {
    result = 'No Parameters';
  }
  else {
    for (var param in e.parameter) {
      Logger.log('In for loop, param=' + param);
      var value = stripQuotes(e.parameter[param]);
      Logger.log(param + ':' + e.parameter[param]);
      switch (param) {

        case 'forceData':
          var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID');
          var sheetName = ssID.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
          var newRow = sheetName.getLastRow() + 1;
          var rowData = [];
          var Curr_Date = new Date();
          rowData[1] = Curr_Date; // Date in column A
          var Curr_Time = Utilities.formatDate(Curr_Date, "Asia/Bangkok", 'HH:mm:ss');
          rowData[2] = Curr_Time; // Time in column B
          rowData[3] = value;
          result = 'OK';
          Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rowData));
          var newRange = sheetName.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
          newRange.setValues([rowData]);
          break;

        case 'forceData2':
          var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID');
          var sheetName = ssID.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
          var newRow = sheetName.getLastRow() + 1;
          var rowData = [];
          rowData[4] = value;
          result = 'OK';
          Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rowData));
          var newRange = sheetName.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
          newRange.setValues([rowData]);
          break;

        default:
          result = "unsupported parameter";
      }
    }
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}
function stripQuotes(value) {
  return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
}

And here's a picture of my problem and also a picture of what I need to do.


Cheers!

I proposed an answer by guessing your situation. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your situation and that was not useful, I apologize.

I believe your goal is as follows.

In your situation, the event object e of doGet(e) has the values of e.parameter.forceData and e.parameter.forceData2.
You want to put the values of var Curr_Date = new Date(), var Curr_Time = Utilities.formatDate(Curr_Date, "Asia/Bangkok", 'HH:mm:ss'), e.parameter.forceData, and e.parameter.forceData2 to columns "B" to "E" of the next empty row of column "B", respectively.

From your showing script and your showing images, I suppose the following situations.

When I saw your showing script, I found rowData[1] = Curr_Date; // Date in column A. From your showing images, I guessed that this is for column "B".
The Spreadsheets var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID'); of case 'forceData': and case 'forceData2': are the same.

When my guess is correct and these are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
Please replace SHEET_ID of var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID'); with your Spreadsheet ID.
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var result = 'Ok';
  if (e.parameter == 'undefined') {
    result = 'No Parameters';
  } else {
    // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
    Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
      const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
      return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
    };
    var Curr_Date = new Date();
    var values = [
      Curr_Date,
      Utilities.formatDate(Curr_Date, "Asia/Bangkok", 'HH:mm:ss'),
      ...['forceData', 'forceData2'].map(k => e.parameter[k] ? stripQuotes(e.parameter[k]) : null)
    ];
    var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID');
    var sheet = ssID.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    sheet.getRange(sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(2) + 1, 2, 1, values.length).setValues([values]);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}

function stripQuotes(value) {
  return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
}


When doGet is executed with valid event object e, values are created and the next empty row of column "B" is retrieved. And, values are put from column "B" of the next empty row of "Sheet1".

Note:

When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

You can see the details of this in my report "Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)".


References:

Web Apps
Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)


Oh and I have one more thing to do, I have another sheet called Sheet2 and I want to send forceData4 to it, I tried to make another doGet function, replace Sheet2 and also forceData4 but it didn't work so can you check this out for me?

And also I forgot to add the "Age" cell. I tried to add it and this happened:
The values var Curr_Date = new Date(),  var Curr_Time = Utilities.formatDate(Curr_Date, "Asia/Bangkok", 'HH:mm:ss'), e.parameter.forceData and e.parameter.forceData2 jumped down to B6 which is the "Age" column, in another word, it didn't put these data to column "C" to "F".

And how to change the date from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy? Thanks

@CoastVu Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue with this question was resolved. About your new various questions, I would like to support you. So, please post it as a new question by including more information. By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Yes of course, thank you for helping me out with this!

I posted my new questions, here's a link!
https://stackoverflow.com/q/78606021/22358888
