How to send data to 2 separated sheets in Google Sheets
I am currently having a project that can measure a force of a punch, I'm using Arduino, ESP32 and Google Sheets to record the data, but I'm still wondering how to send data to 2 different sheets in google sheets. Let's make an example right here, the data that Sheet1 will receive is "forceData1", "forceData2", "forceData3" and the data that Sheet2 receive will be "forceData4" and "forceData5".
I have my picture of my expectation right here:
My expectation of Sheet2
Here's my code
*The code is from my other question
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var result = 'Ok';
  if (e.parameter == 'undefined') {
    result = 'No Parameters';
  } else {
    // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639 (This is the user who written this, I still put this here just in case)
    Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
      const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
      return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
    };
    var Curr_Date = new Date();
    var values = [
      Curr_Date,
      Utilities.formatDate(Curr_Date, "Asia/Bangkok", 'HH:mm:ss'),
      ...['forceData', 'forceData2', 'forceData3'].map(k => e.parameter[k] ? stripQuotes(e.parameter[k]) : null)
    ];
    var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID');
    var sheet = ssID.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    sheet.getRange(sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(2) + 1, 2, 1, values.length).setValues([values]);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}

function stripQuotes(value) {
  return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");

Oh and I have 2 more small problem with this:
The first one is how to change the date from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy? (If mm/dd/yyyy is by default then we can pass this problem)
And the second one is that  I forgot to add the "Age" cell. I tried to add it and this happened: The values var Curr_Date = new Date(), var Curr_Time = Utilities.formatDate(Curr_Date, "Asia/Bangkok", 'HH:mm:ss'), e.parameter.forceData, e.parameter.forceData2 and e.parameter.forceData3 jumped down to B6 which is the "Age" column, in another word, it didn't put these data to columns "C" to "F".
Heres's a picture of this problem and my expectation!
The problem with the "Age" cell/
My expectation of this "Age" cell problem
I hope you guys can help me out, Cheers!

In your situation, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
Please replace 'SHEET_ID' with your situation.
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var result = 'Ok';
  if (e.parameter == 'undefined') {
    result = 'No Parameters';
  } else {
    // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
    Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
      const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
      return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
    };
    var Curr_Date = new Date();
    var prefix = [
      Utilities.formatDate(Curr_Date, "Asia/Bangkok", 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
      Utilities.formatDate(Curr_Date, "Asia/Bangkok", 'HH:mm:ss'),
    ];
    var v1 = ["forceData1", "forceData2", "forceData3"].map(k => e.parameter[k] ? stripQuotes(e.parameter[k]) : "");
    var v2 = ["forceData4", "forceData5"].map(k => e.parameter[k] ? stripQuotes(e.parameter[k]) : "");
    var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID');
    [v1, v2].forEach((v, i) => {
      if (v.join("") != "") {
        var values = [...prefix, ...v];
        var sheet = ssID.getSheetByName(`Sheet${i + 1}`);
        sheet.getRange(sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(3) + 1, 3, 1, values.length).setValues([values]);
      }
    });
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}

function stripQuotes(value) {
  return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
}


In this modified script, the values "forceData1", "forceData2", "forceData3" are put from column "C" of "Sheet1". The values "forceData4", "forceData5" are put from column "C" of "Sheet2".

Note:

When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

You can see the details of this in my report "Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)".


References:

Web Apps
Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)

